# The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user “{user}”, but the current user is “”

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having problems with my anti-forgery token after a form has been submitted. I keep on getting this error message:

> The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user “{user}”, but the current user is “”

The difference between what other have asked here and with mine is that it's say the current user is blank and the anti-forgery token is looking for a user.  This makes no sense because when I checked **HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name** and **Membership.GetUser().UserName**, they do have the user anti-forgery token is looking for. This is not really making any sense.

**NewRecordEntry.cshtml**

```
<h2>New Record</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div id="new-record-entry">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.recordTypeID, Model.GetRecordTypeList())
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="NewRecordEntry" id="continue" size="11" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult NewRecordEntry(FormCollection frm, NewRecordEntryViewModel nrevm)
    {
        TempData["NewRecordEntry"] = nrevm;
        return RedirectToAction("NewRecord", "FakeController");
    }
```

**Authentication Filter**

```
public class FakeAuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Get userData stored in a session. Workplace environment does not allow cookies
        UserData userData = (UserData) filterContext.HttpContext.Session[UserInfo.SessionUser];
        if (userData != null)
        {
            // Get identity and principal
            var identity = new GenericIdentity(UserInfo.SessionUser, "Forms");
            var principal = new FakePrincipal(identity);

            principal.UserData = userData;

            // Set the context user.
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login");
        }
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
    }
  }
```

**Membership**

```
public class FakeMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        // Check if this is a valid user.
        // The application sends the username and password to an LDAP DLL which
        //   reurns "Success" if it was a match.
        string result = LoginService.AuthenticateUser(username, password);
        if (result == "Success")
        {
             return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {

        if (LoginService.UserData != null)
        {
            return new MembershipUser("FakeMembershipProvider", 
                username, LoginService.UserData.UserID,
                null, null, null, true, false,
                DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, 
                DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Login Post Controller**

```
#region Login Post Controllers
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection frm, LoginViewModel lvm, string returnUrl)
    {
        List<string> errorList = null;
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string result = Services.ValidateLogin(lvm);

                if (result == "Success")
                {
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)
                        && returnUrl.Length > 1
                        && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return base.Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    return base.RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["errors"] = result;
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", result);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errorList = Services.AddErrorMesagesToView(ModelState);
                TempData["errors"] = errorList;
            }
            //return base.RedirectToAction("Admin", new { section = section });
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(new LoginViewModel());
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ne)
        {
            if (ne.Source != null)
                Console.WriteLine("NullReferenceException source: {0}", ne.Source);
        }
        catch (HttpException he)
        {
            if (he.Source != null)
                Console.WriteLine("HttpException source: {0}", he.Source);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.Source != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Exception source: {0}", e.Source);
        }
        finally
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
        }

        return base.RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
    #endregion
```

**ValidateLogin**

```
    public static string ValidateLogin(LoginViewModel lvm)
    {
        /* string ldapServer = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAPServer"];
        string result = Fakeauthenticate.Fakeauth.LdapAuth(lvm.Login, lvm.Password, ldapServer);
         */
        string result = null;
        const int INACTIVE = 1;

        FakeEntities db = new FakeEntities();

        // This is the only feasible way to call an SQL user-defined scalar function
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT [dbo].[Util_GetUserActivationStatus] ({0})";
        Object[] parameters = { lvm.Login };
        int status = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sqlQuery, parameters).FirstOrDefault();

        if (status == INACTIVE)
        {
            return "The user is currently locked out.";
        }

        if (Membership.ValidateUser(lvm.Login, lvm.Password))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[UserInfo.SessionUser] = LoginBusiness.GetUserData(lvm.Login);
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = UserInfo.Timeout;

            result = "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            result = LoginBusiness.AuthenticateUser(lvm.Login, lvm.Password);
            if (result == "Login_Failure")
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session[lvm.Login] == null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session[lvm.Login] = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    uint loginFailures = (uint)HttpContext.Current.Session[lvm.Login];
                    HttpContext.Current.Session[lvm.Login] = ++loginFailures;

                    // If the maximum number of login failures have been reached, then lock the user out.
                    if ((uint)HttpContext.Current.Session[lvm.Login] == UserInfo.MAX_LOGIN_FAILURES)
                    {
                        db.Util_LockUserOut(lvm.Login);
                        return "Your account has been temporarily locked.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Show some code maybe?

Comment: What part of the code to show?

Comment: The parts you consider relevant...

Comment: Okay, I added some code.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work on any of the forms that has [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] for their post actions. I'm very stuck here.

Comment: I added more code, with the login procedures. Maybe this can be of help.

Comment: This line is the problem `HttpContext.Current.User = principal;` If you remove this, it'll work. However, I'm not sure why or what a good solution is. I currently set Thread.Current to the principal but then that doesn't work 100% of the time.

Comment: Thanks, but I got it working.

Comment: @AndyNarain how did you get it working? I ran into this today as well on an AngularJS (aka Angular 1.x) app. Mine will even jump back and forth from throwing the exception to being happy again every few POSTs.

Comment: So I realized yesterday that some % of the time .Net is getting "" for the user. To solve this I protected all my `[HttpPost] [ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken]` with `[Authorize]`. I had missed it on 2 methods. Now it detected the empty user as a 401 and then Chrome resends the request with the proper authorized user included.

Comment: @AndyNarain how did you fix your issue?

Comment: I don't remember.  I have to look at my code again and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your FakeAuthenticationFilter. I'm guessing you are using this filter on the controller action which loads the page. FakeAuthenticationFilter sets HttpContext.Current.User = new FakePrincipal(identity). This principal probably has a Name property, which is the user you see in the error message. .NET uses this Principal to generate the tokens on the page, but when you submit the tokens, the HttpContext will not have the same Principal.

A solution could be to put FakeAuthenticationFilter on your NewRecordEntry Action.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if there is more than one `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your form. If yes, remove all but one.

Also make sure that you are not submitting the form twice. This will mess up the `AntiForgeryToken`.

If you want to disable this check, add the following to your `Application_Start` method:

```
AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true
```

Comment: Is that basically the only way?

Comment: It depends. Where are you using this anti forgery token?

Comment: Pretty much when I'm about to create a new record. The first web page ask for the type of record. That's a form. After that it then goes the new records form, based on the type.  By the way, I tried what you suggested, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Do you have two @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in your form?

Comment: Yes I do. If you take a look at the first code sample (NewRecordEntry.cshtml), you can see that it's at the 4th line.

Comment: My question was if you have two of them :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see that. :P  No I don't. Just one.

Comment: Is there any chance that you're submitting the form twice? Like double click the submit button?

Comment: I don't think so. I only have to click on the submit button once. Let me trace through the problem to see if the program is submitting twice. I wished I had 15.

Comment: Nope. It only submit once. The head scratcher here is that it says the current user is blank, when I clearly do add a user.

Comment: Still having problems with this error. Please help.

Comment: Are you injecting the user on every request or just on login?

Comment: It should be fairly easy to verify. You can remove the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() and check if on submit the user is actually there.

Comment: Okay, so I assume all I have to do is to see if the user exist after I submit? Okay, that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Sorry for taking long, but I had a tight deadline assignment.  Anyhow, after I submitted, I did check to see if the user existed, by using "HttpContext.User.Identity.Name" and it did show "UserData" as the name.

Comment: I also noticed that there is one place that @Html.AntiForgeryToken() does work, and that's at the Login post controller. I hope that little info helps

Comment: Hello again. I'm getting back at this issue. Like I stated in my previous post, the only place the Html.AntiForgeryToken() code works is at the Login post controller. I think I'm injecting the user in every request, but I'm not sure. based on my reply, back in 2014/12/9.